# Understanding Signal Representation and Processing using Continuous Bag of Words (CBOW) Model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, signal-processing, word-embedding

I'm attempting to improve the representation of my signal at each time step using the CBOW method. However, my signal consists of 1000 time steps, which is too large to work with. To address this, I have reduced the size of my signal to approximately 50 points through the use of a sampling rate and delta encoding.

I have already created the context and target datasets using a window size of 4. I have a total of 280 training signals. As a result, my context dataset has a shape of (280, 54, 4), meaning it consists of 280 samples, each divided into 54 segments, and each segment contains 4 contexts. My target dataset has a shape of (280, 54), meaning it has 280 samples, with each sample containing 54 targets.

However, my CBOW model is not performing as expected and I suspect the issue may be related to the shape of my training dataset. The following is my code.

```
class CBOW(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocabulary_size, embedding_size, context_window_size):
        super(CBOW, self).__init__()
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(embedding_size, vocabulary_size)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        embeds = self.embeddings(inputs).mean(dim=1)
        out = self.linear(embeds)
        return out

vocabulary_size= 1302
embedding_size = 10
context_window_size = 4
num_epochs = 50
model = CBOW(vocabulary_size, embedding_size, context_window_size)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

and i got an error of  “index out of range in self” occurs at

```
embeds = self.embeddings(inputs).mean(dim=1)
```

I guess the problem may be related to the shape of my data, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://github.com/alvations/tsundoku/blob/master/completed/Session%203%20-%20Using%20Word2Vec%20to%20understand%20NLP%20Task.ipynb